# Trouble with Console.ReadLine in vscode

Tags: c#

Hey y'all I'm writing my first program and I've chosen C#. I'm trying to write a little dialogue at the beginning of what will be a multiple choice quiz. According to youtube videos and forums I should be able to do a WriteLine followed by a blank ReadLine and the program should continue after anything is entered. But when I provide it with input it just drops down a line and continues to wait for a prompt. Is this an issue caused by vscode? Also I am just modifying the basic hello world script. Here is some code. thanks.

```
using System;

namespace C_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In 5 seconds the teacher will begin to speak...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You will be tested for aptitude in the realm of being a worthy human.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *But when I provide it with input it just drops down a line and continues to wait for a prompt.* By "drops down a line" do you mean the second line of text is shown? You're calling `ReadLine` twice, so after you enter a line it will continue to the next `ReadLine` and wait for you to enter a line again.

Comment: When it comes to properly using and understanding an API, I would suggest relying on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.readline) and books, not YouTube videos or forums or even a Q&A site like this.

Comment: "do you mean the second line of text is shown?" No. There is an arrow to the left and a prompt if I hit enter or anything else then enter it adds another arrow on the next line below and continues to prompt me. Same happens 4,5,and 6 strokes of the enter button

Comment: @BACON: "When it comes to properly using and understanding an API, I would suggest relying on documentation and books, not YouTube videos or forums or even a Q&A site like this." TBH This is clearly solid advice. However, I'm having trouble understanding the language on microsofts website and other technical documents. Until I'm in a little deeper I think youtube, forums, this site, etc are more accessible to me as a layman.

Comment: Perhaps I should have included "quality instruction" (courses, blogs, etc. from subject matter experts) as a third suggestion. That might overcome the obstacle of accessibility without relying on, well, yahoos on the internet. Also, I tried your code and see what the problem is: it's stuck in the `Debug Console`. See [https://stackoverflow.com/q/41195432/150605](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195432/debug-console-window-cannot-accept-console-readline-input-during-debugging/45479761).  (It wasn't an API usage issue after all, so I suppose that might make me one of those same yahoos.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug Console window cannot accept Console.ReadLine() input during debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195432/debug-console-window-cannot-accept-console-readline-input-during-debugging)

Comment: Yes, in fact, it does. @Barns got to me first though.

Answer (score 10):

This is an issue with the Visual Studio Code environment. The `launch.json` contains setting that will control the way your app executes.

By default the attribute: "console" is set to the value "internalConsole". So it looks like this:
"console": "internalConsole"

In order to use `Console.ReadLine();` or `Console.ReadKey();` change to: 
           "console": "integratedTerminal"

And then switch to "Terminal" in the lower panel while debugging.

In order to 'automatically' switch to the "Terminal" panel add:
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"