# My visual studio code doesn't sequence programs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I code in C#, when I run code in visual studio code only the first console.WriteLine() statement will actually execute. I code in C# and I just installed visual studio code and the SDK for c#.

Heres the code I executed - a simple program to add 2 numbers

```cs
using System;

namespace MyApp 
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number 1: ");
            int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number 2: ");
            int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
        
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

The output is this:

> Enter number 1:

Then when i enter a number it doesn't do anything else, like ask me what number 2 should be.

Comment: Are you entering valid integers, and no other characters? Seems to work fine on my machine. Any breakpoints set in the editor?

Comment: @Jonathan no breakpoints are used and im using integers between 1 and 10

Comment: Can you change [console](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window) to a different value (like `externalTerminal`), and then check again ?

Comment: Did you press Enter key after numeric value?

Comment: Note that you should almost always use `int.TryParse` rather than `int.Parse`

Comment: @JonasH, whats the difference? i looked it up but im still a bit unsure. Its it just that tryparse will return a boolean value to determine success in converting?

Comment: `int.Parse` will throw an Exception when it fails. (For example enter the text "number" in stead of a number )

Comment: If the user enters something other than a number you likely want to ask him/her to reenter it. So you put your tryParse into a loop that completes when the parsing succeeds. You do not want to use exceptions for this as it requires more code, and entering the incorrect number is not really an error or "exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs fine on my machine.

Few things to check:

1. Check if there are any [breakpoints set in the editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints) by accident.
2. Is the console closing after input or doing anything at all?
3. Check [this answer on another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479761/5424516) (Use `integratedTerminal`).
4. To run the code, use the terminal command `dotnet run`.

I'd also recommend using a try/catch to check if there's any formatting exceptions appearing. Example:

```cs
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number 1: ");
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number 2: ");
    int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


    int sum = num1 + num2;
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
catch(FormatException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That way you can tell immediately if there's an error when running the code.

Comment: each time i execute the program i get this message come up a few times in the debug console, is this normal?

Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: Can you check my updated answer and specifically step 3?

Comment: this generates the same problem as before, my output is still ' enter number 1: ', and then when i enter a number nothing happens

Comment: Are you running the code via the terminal command `dotnet run` or a different way?

Comment: I was using dotnet build, dotnet run works. Sorry I'm new to this, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: No worries! Remember, if you set the parameter according to step 3, you will have to change the window from "Debug Console" to "Terminal" in order to actually input anything. If you found the answer helpful and resolved the issue, feel free to mark as solved!